# ContentObserver onChange() method gets called many times

Tags: android, contentobserver

I have requirement to track any new image file of type .jpg created on device.
I have done this using `ContentObserver` on `MediaStore` using below class `MediaStoreObserver` and,
registering the same in one of my service.

I have noticed that `onChange()` method gets called many times for a single file creation.
I understand that media file created gets updated in many tables of `MediaStore` hence `onChange()` gets called many times.

My question: How to register to `MediaStore` for ONLY image file create/edit operation ?

-Thanks in advance,
Manju

```
    private class MediaStoreObserver extends ContentObserver {
    public MediaStoreObserver() {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        //check image file changes in MediaStore
        readFromMediaStore(_context,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    }
}

//register for external media changes for image files
if(mediaStoreObserver!=null){
  _context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        false,mediaStoreObserver);
```

Comment: Where did you unregister this observer?? If you didn't check if your code register this observer multiple times.

Comment: This is registered in a service onCreate(), and the same gets de-registered in onDestroy() of my service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** You can't, it's the provider which sends `notifyChange` (received with observers `onChange`) whenever something is: updated/inserted/deleted

**Longer answer:** This is what would've done to achieve what you want (How to register to MediaStore for ONLY image file create/edit operation ?):

Read image table from MediaStore upon start and store the _data column (file paths), in a sorted `collection`, a sorted `collection` with paths (strings). And whenever you receive an `onChange` call make a new collection of the above sort, then loop over the new collection and search the original collection you created , with binary search (since the collection is sorted and we want to keep the time complexity low). This would lead to a quite effective implementation with running time of O(n*logn).

Or in pseudo code:

```
1. Read current image columns from media store (the `_data column as projection)
2. Store result in a collection, with string type
3. Sort collection
4. Upon `onChange` is received, make a new collection as step 1-3
5. Loop over collection created in 4 and search each string you take out with 
binary search in the sorted collection you got from step 3, if item is not found 
then the item is new
6. Make the collection in 4 the current cached version of mediastore 
7. Time complexity is O(n*log n) for the above algorithm
```

**Edit** for the updated file part i would read the date modified field from MediaStore whenever my search in step 5 hits, that would mean that you should actually **store both file (uri) and date modified** in a data class, but as search lookup use file path. Whenever file is found you should check if the modified dates match, if not then it's an updated file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and fixed it by removing `super.onchange` from my `onchange` override.

Comment: This does not work for me. I get an ANR when I do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange, @Nullable Uri uri) {
   super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
    if (uri == null) return;
    if (!uri.equals(Uri.parse("content://settings/system/volume_music_speaker"))) 
          return;
    //your code here...
}
```